# Cakephp image -Can not determine the mimetype

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

cakephp 2.3

I'm uploading an image and I have an error saying that:

```
Can not determine the mimetype.

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
```

On my Model this is a part of my $validation

```
'file_name' => array(
            'uploadError' => array(
                'rule' =>'uploadError',
                'message' => 'Your image upload failed',
                'allowEmpty' => FALSE,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
            'mimeType' => array(
                'rule' => array('mimeType', array('image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg')),
                'message' => 'Please only upload images (gif, png, jpg).',
                'allowEmpty' => FALSE,
                ),
            'fileSize' => array(
                'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '2MB'),
                'message' => 'Your image must be less than 2MB or(2048ko).',
                'allowEmpty' => FALSE,
                ),
            'processCoverUpload' => array(
                'rule' => 'processCoverUpload',
                'message' => 'Unable to process cover image upload.',
                'allowEmpty' => FALSE,
                ),
            'unique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'This file name is already exist in your folder',
                'required' => 'create',
                'allowEmpty' => FALSE,
                ),
        ),
```

I'm only allow 3 types of mimetype. any help?

Comment: PHP Version? Do you have your form set to type `file`?

Comment: Thks Tigran. Yes I have  `code` <?php echo $this->Form->create('Image', array('type' => 'file')); ?> .....echo $this->Form->input('file_name', array('type' => 'file')); ...PHP version 5.3

Comment: Do you have debug set to 2? Is there more than Internal Error message?

Comment: Yes I do have it set to 2. I have one Internal Error (the one I posted) and all the other is stack Trace...

Comment: Do you have `fileinfo` extension on your server? If not, it uses `mime_content_type` which is deprecated, so it might not be so clever...

Comment: @PapoucheGuinslyzinho did you ever get this to work and also did the unique work since I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just ran into exactly the same problem. Thanx to some other comments which pointed me in the right direction, here is my solution:
Edit php.ini (\xampp\php\php.ini on Win7) search for `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` and uncomment it.

FYI: I'm running xampp 1.7.7 [Apache:2.2.21; PHP:5.3.8; MySQL:5.5.16]. Hopefully on newer xampp versions the extension is enabled by default.

Comment: I think you need to restart xampp after the changes and then the problem is fixed